# I can not addimage to ad revive server

Tags: php, openx

I want to upload ad image to ad revive server, when i create or update d banner.
when i click to save changes page will response the **The connection time out.**
.

I try to change the file permissions 0755 to 0777. but sill i can upload/change ad image.

Log Output (debug.log):
May 13 21:15:36 +0000 OX-5af8aaf8338bc [  warning]  Declaration of HTML_QuickForm_file::_findValue() should be compatible with HTML_QuickForm_element::_findValue(&$values)

I can't understand the above log output.

Please help me to understand and debug.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The warning you paste is because the class being used is overriding a static function `_findValue`, and declares it differently than the parent class.

You can get rid of that warning by changing the line in the child class (probably given by the warning: "in file... at line...") from

```
public (or protected) static function _findValue() {
```

to

```
public (or protected) static function _findValue(&$values) {
```

As for what is causing the timeout, I'm afraid there are just too many possibilities. Try inspecting the communication using Firefox or Chrome Web Developer Tools, see whether anything comes up.

Failing that, you'd need to debug the server, either by using a developer setup (IDE plus remote debugger, say XDebug or Zend) or the old fashioned, plodding way by inserting `die()` statements along the execution path. Both require some experience and some time. If you've never done it, I'm afraid you need to find someone who can.